# Как присвоить значение переменной внешнего класса из внутреннего?

Tags: c++

Пример:

```
class Animal {
public: 
    int age;

    class Dog {
        int a;

        Dog() {
            int a=5;
            age = a;// ERROR
        }
    };
};
```

> "age переменная не существует".

С наследственными классами все понятно как они обмениваются с базовыми. А как быть когда класс не наследственный, а внутренний? Объявлен внутри главного класса.

Comment: Передавайте в конструкторе указатель на внешний объект, иного переносимого пути не вижу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простое размещение определения одного класса внутри другого никак не связывает экземпляры (объекты) этих классов. Для того, чтобы обратиться к полю `age` класса `Animal`, внутренний класс `Dog` должен знать с каким экземпляром ему работать. Например, это можно сделать, передав ссылку/указатель на экземпляр такого класса в конструктор:

```
Dog(Animal* ani) {
ani->age = a;
```

По сути, помещение определение одного класса внутрь другого лишь удлиняет полное имя вложенного класса, т.е. во внешнем коде это будет не `Dog`, а `Animal::Dog`. Дополнительно вложенный класс может иметь доступ к непубличным полям родительского класса, но чтобы с ними работать всё равно нужно знать экземпляр (конкретный объект) этого родительского класса.